# How to fix fail to resolve Error:Failed to resolve identitytoolkit api11 & fbv4

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to integrate the gitkit login into my app.
In the guide it says that in need to add the following lines:

```
compile(name:'identitytoolkit-api11', ext:'aar')
compile(name:'identitytoolkit_fbv4', ext:'jar')
```

But i'm getting 'Failed to resolve' error for both of them.
I've put both of the files in my libs directory.
How do I fix it?
By the way, I have another solution in which I add

```
compile 'com.google.identitytoolkit:gitkitclient:1.2.3'
```

In my gradle but then i get an error saying that it doesnt recognize

```
import com.google.identitytoolkit.IdToken;
```

but it does recognize other import such as

```
import com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitClient;
import com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following within the repositories block:

```
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
```

For example, the demo project has the following:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```